# Show that $\| y\| =1$ and $\| y-x_j\|\geq \| x_j\|$

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

I have an idea to solve this exercise but I am confused. The exercise says:

Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional normed vector space over $\mathbb{K}$, where $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$

Let $x_1, x_2, \dots ,x_n\in X$. Show that there exists $y\in X$ such that $\| y\| =1$ and $\| y-x_j\|\geq \| x_j\|$  for all $j=1,2, \dots ,n$.
We know that if $0≠x\in X$, then there exists $f\in X^*$ such that $\|f\|=1$ and $f(x)=\mid \mid x\mid \mid$.

I was thinking we can show that $f(y)=1$ for some $y\in X$ then we are done. Or else I am thinking that we can say $\|f(y)\|= \| \| y\| \|=\|y\|=\|f\|\|y\|\Leftrightarrow \|y\|=\frac{\|f(y)\|}{\|f\|}$, and probably try to show that $\frac{\|f(y)\|}{\|f\|}=1$, but I don't know how I would do that.

Thank you

Comment: I think we would rather have $y \in \mathrm{ker} f$...

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right track. For $1 \le j \le n$ let $f_j \in X^*$ be a bounded functional such that $f_j(x_j) = \|x_j\|$ and $\|f_j\| =1$. Then the intersection of kernels $$\bigcap_{j=1}^n \ker f_j$$
is a nontrivial subspace of $X$. Indeed, we can define a linear map $f : X \to \Bbb{K}^n$ by $f(x) = (f_1(x), \ldots, f_n(x))$. Then $\ker f = \bigcap_{j=1}^n \ker f_j$ so if $\bigcap_{j=1}^n \ker f_j = \{0\}$ we would have that $f$ is an injective linear map from an infinite-dimensional space $X$ to a finite-dimensional space $\Bbb{K}^n$. This is a contradiction so $\bigcap_{j=1}^n \ker f_j$ is nontrivial.

Pick $y \in \bigcap_{j=1}^n \ker f_j$ such that $\|y\|=1$ and notice
$$\|y-x_j\| = \|f_j\|\|y-x_j\| \ge |f_j(y-x_j)| = |f_j(y)-f_j(x_j)| = |0-\|x_j\||=\|x_j\|$$

which proves the claim.

Comment: Hi! How do you get the first inequality? I mean why is it possible to write $\|f_j\|\|y-x_j\| \ge |f_j(y-x_j)|$? And how do you have that $\|y\| =1$

Comment: If $y\in \cap_{j=1}^n \ker(f_j)$ then I thought we’d have $\|y\|= f_j(y)=0$?

Comment: @Sumi For every $f \in X^*$ and $x \in X$ we have $|f(x)| \le \|f\|\|x\|$ by definition of the operator norm. We can pick a nonzero $z \in \bigcap_{j=1}^n \ker f_j$ so define $y := \frac{z}{\|z\|}$. Then $\|y\|=1$. For your second comment, we only have $f_j(x_j) = \|x_j\|$, not $f_j(y)=\|y\|$.

Comment: By the operator norm definition shouldn't it be $\|f(x)\| \leq \|f\| \|x\|$ instead of $|f(x)| \leq \|f\| \|x\|$ ? Thank you so much for your help! The last part makes sense :)

Comment: @Sumi Yes, but the norm in $\Bbb{K}$ is the absolute value $|\cdot|$.